# What is the best way to visualize a single numeric variable as a heatmap?

Tags: data-visualization, density-function

I'm a hobbyist programmer whose friend recently took a business trip overseas.  He's polled our mutual friends for bets on the size of his email inbox when he returns.  I'd like to visualize this as a one-dimensional heatmap where color reflects a kind of density of guesses for that value.  I understand I could create a histogram and find a way to translate its values into color values.  However, the histogram bins would create janky transitions in color.  Is there a way to create an appropriate, continuous function for prettier output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use density and fields::colorbar.plot

```
require(fields)
plot(1:10, rep(1,10), ylim=c(0,10))
 colorbar.plot( 2, 4, 800*density(rgamma(100, shape=2))$y)
 colorbar.plot( 2, 5, 800*density(rexp(100))$y)
 colorbar.plot( 2, 6, 800*density(rnorm(100))$y)
 colorbar.plot( 2, 7, 800*density(rlnorm(100))$y)
 text(6,4, "Gamma")
 text(6,5, "Exponential")
 text(6,6, "Normal")
 text(6,7, "LogNormal")
```

[image]

Comment: What programming language/system is this?

Comment: This is done in R. I just assumed anyone who wanted a heatmap would be using R or S, since none of the statistical languages I worked with in the past had that facility, but I guess they may have caught up if your expectation was to get a heatmap implemented in another language.

Comment: The rainbow/jet colormap is generally a bad idea. http://www.jwave.vt.edu/~rkriz/Projects/create_color_table/color_07.pdf